# Update local state from redux state?store.subscribe is not getting called to update step in stepzilla

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have to use redux state to maintain state of steps in stepzilla.

```
class MainWizard extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      CurrentWizardStep : 0,
    };

    store.subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Inside subscribe')
        this.setState({
            CurrentWizardStep : store.getState().selectedWizradStep
        });
      });
    }
render() {
    const steps =
        [
            { name: 'step1', component: <step1/> },
            { name: 'step2', component: <step2 /> },
            { name: 'step3', component: <step3 /> },
        ];
    return (
        <article className='step-progress'>
            <StepZilla
                steps={steps}
                preventEnterSubmission={true}
                nextTextOnFinalActinonStep={'Save'}
                hocValidationAppliedTo={[3]}
                //startAtStep={window.sessionStorage.getItem('step') ? parseFloat(window.sessionStorage.getItem('step')) : 0}
                startAtStep = {this.state.CurrentWizardStep}
                //onStepChange={(step) => window.sessionStorage.setItem('step', step)}
                showNavigation={false}
            />
        </article>
    );
}
```

}

redux state is getting update but after dispatch store.subscribe is not getting called?

Thanks in advance.

Shraddha

Comment: You mean, `console.log('Inside subscribe')` doesnt show up? Please add your imports and dispatch functions too. Doesnt feel like theres  a in the available code.

Comment: yes console.log('Inside subscribe') is not showing up.

Comment: Actions->function setMainWizardStep(step) {
    
    return {
        type: SET_MAIN_WIZARD_STEP,
        Wizard: {
            selectedWizradStep: step
        }
    }
}

export function selectMainWizardStep(step) {
 console.log('action called');
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(setMainWizardStep(step))
    }
}

Comment: Reducer->case ActionTypes.SET_MAIN_WIZARD_STEP:{
            console.log('Wizard Reducer Called'+action.Wizard.selectedWizradStep)
            return{                
                ...state,
                selectedWizradStep: action.Wizard.selectedWizradStep
            }
        }